# Django unique relation

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model called Event and a model called Person. I want to be able to define roles for an event and be able to assign many Persons to an events role. Each person can only be part of one role for an Event. What is the best way to create this relationship in my models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this?

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...

# a role is created and assigned to an event.
class Role(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    ...


# person is created and assigned a role. I would foreignkey to the role so the person can only be assigned to one role. And not several roles assigned to one person.
class Person(models.Model):
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)
    ...
```

Create an Event: Concert

Create a Role: Bouncer.event = Concert

Create some Persons: Jim.role = Bouncer, John.role = Bouncer, etc..

Comment: With this only one person can be in a Role. I need many people to be in a role but only one role per event.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. That would be true if "unique" was set to true. ` role = models.ForeignKey(Role, unique=True) ` How it is, you can create several Person objects and point them all to the same Role object then point that Role object to an Event object.

Comment: Ok so what is there that is saying that Jim can only be a bouncer and not some other role for the event?

Comment: @barchiesi The nature of a foreign key relationship prevents him from being assigned to any other role at the same time. If you used a manytomany relationship (`role = models.ManyToManyField(Role)`)then he could be assigned to multiple roles.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Role model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    # ...

class Person(models.Model):
    # ...

class Role(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    # ...
```

This way, an event can have several roles, each of them being managed by a single person.

Comment: I want each role to have many persons but each person can be in only one role for a specific event.